# Docker Compose - Wiremock not able to answer REST call from SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring Application that is making REST calls that is intercepted by Wiremock, running this setup on my local machine works well but when running dockerized I can see that the request reaches Wiremock but nothing comes back so from the application side it looks like the connection was refused. Where did the response go?

Stripped version of my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    test-service-application:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-local
        hostname: test-service
        privileged: true
        ports:
            - "22101:22101" # Application port
        environment:
            - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local"

    wiremock:
        image: 'wiremock/wiremock:2.32.0'
        container_name: 'wiremock'
        ports:
            - "8443:8080" # Web browser
            - "30121:8080" # Service #1
        environment:
            https-port: 8443
            http-port: 8443
```

And REST call:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()))
    .build();

webClient
    .method(HttpMethod.GET)
    .uri("http://localhost:30121/test-endpoint/")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(MyClassDTO)
    .block();
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because Docker actually can build an own internal network and docker-compose does this by default.
The hostname inside of docker is the container name or -using docker-compose- the service name.
In your app the correct request URL would be `http://wiremock:30121/test-endpoint/`

Comment: Oh, I see! Is it possible to get it to use localhost the same way it does on my local machine instead of going of container name? I don't want to maintain two sets of properties to cover both scenarios for my colleagues.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. It is just the way the network driver ([bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)) works: Every container gets an own hostname and ip address in this virtual network.

Comment: Hmm, might open up another can of worms but what about using Overlay or another type of network driver?

Comment: You can use, the host network to use localhost. just by trying this on container: docker run --network="host", it will use your local network

Comment: Using host as network mode didn't help, made the test suite not able to reach either of the containers.

Comment: @someron I switched to wiremock in my connection string like you suggested but it looks like the setup is still broken the same way. The application is able to send to wiremock but wiremock response never comes back to the application thus it must still communicate through localhost is my presumption.

Answer (score 2):

After A LOT of googling I finally found the answer to my problem by using **host.docker.internal** as the DNS string instead of container name. This because using the container name it wouldn't route it correctly through the ports I wanted.